# responsive website html/css

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

I'm trying to make a responsive photography website but I'm having trouble getting it the way I want it. I'm using Dreamweaver and have created responsive images that look great on my screen. I've specified that one image must float left and the other float right, so that they fit nicely beside each other. However, when I make the screen smaller, the images fold under each other. What I actually want is for them to shrink together, maintaining the same layout. What is the best way to establish this?

Comment: This is a really broad question. Too broad for us here on stack. You need to at least make an attempt at writing the code, and then post it. And then we can help you.

Comment: set their width to 50% or less if you have margins

Answer (score 0):

You need to play with the image size, I advise you to read about media querys for responsive web design, with that you can choose the different size according the screen size in different devices